# Allowing multiple users access to forms

Tags: cognito-forms

I imported forms from Adobe FormsCentral.  I want to know if anyone knows how to allow multiple users to access the forms to make changes, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I am a developer for [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

Currently our systems only supports one user for each account. We are currently working on Multiple User support. You can follow our progress on this over on our [Idea Board](https://trello.com/c/FDjI6zak). We hope to have this feature out in our next release and will let our users know when this feature is available.